# Create-react-app never ends and doesn’t create any app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

It has been 2 hours me running npx Create-react-app. the command does not end, my internet connection is good

[image: create-react-app never ends and doesn’t create any app]

Comment: I think react app is created. press ctrl + c and check the app directory

Comment: Alternatively, you can try `yarn create` if npx giving you trouble. You just have to install yarn

Comment: `yarn create react-app yourappname` also creates issues as of late with superuser access.

Comment: Try exiting with `ctrl + c` and check the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a well-known bug for `create-react-app` tool on Windows 10. You have to disable `Quick Edit mode` in your terminal preferences. If you are pasting CRA line from the internet it will 'expect' key combination from the user (which at this point it shouldn't) to complete the task.

How to disable:

1. Open terminal
2. On the title bar right click and select `Preferences`
3. Tab `Options`
4. Uncheck `Quick Edit Mode`
5. Press `OK`

This would remove necessity to press `Ctrl+C`and to see if the application is created.

Troubleshooting:

In some cases you have to restart the terminal in order to make it work.
EDIT: Not sure if that solution will work on Windows 7. Please leave the comments if that works.