# Can't install npm packages on create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I wanted to work on a project so I used `npx create-react-app app-name`. I got an error call back err!, I did some research and I was told to update npm. By typing `npm update @latest`. Then it lead to another issue

```
npm Err! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\DELL\Documents\react-expenses-tracker
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file
npm ERR! enoent
```

I have deleted node js and installed it again.
Usually  if I have issues like this y used to type `npm cache clean --force` and everything will work fine again but now it shows a warning .

---

**Edit:** My OS is Windows.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226082/npm-start-does-not-work-for-ract-template-project?%3Fr=SearchResults) may help resolve the issue. Try running `npm config delete script-shell` - that should reset the shell to `cmd` _(the default shell npm utilizes on Windows)_ and not `bash` _(the default shell npm utilizes on *nix)_

Comment: @RobC thanks it works again, but now npx create-react-app my-app takes over 3hrs and it hasn't been created yet, don't know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the solution given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718394/create-react-app-never-ends-and-doesn-t-create-any-app?%3Fr=SearchResults).